# TSQL: passing ids from select clause to stored procedure

Tags: php, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure called SELECT_DESCRIPTION that receives an id and returns a Description field I need to show in my page.

Now I want to create a new procedure that having a number of ids coming from a select clause like this:

```
SELECT id FROM MYTABLE
```

Can pass it to the SELECT_DESCRIPTION procedure so I can have the same number of descriptions

If I was using php I would be doing something like this:

```
$sql=”SELECT id FROM MYTABLE”;
$result = mysql_query($sql) //using mysql to make the example faster but TSQL is what I use
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $newSql = "EXEC SELECT_DESCRIPTION @id = '$row[‘id’]'"; 
//do whatever with $newSql

}
```

But I need to use a procedure. Is is possible to do it? How can I do it?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Retagging to mysql as per your php source

Comment: I don't know mysql syntax, but you should be able to just SELECT id, SELECT_DESCRIPTION(id) FROM MYTABLE, no?

Comment: sorry, no mysql but TSQL the php was something to guide, to make it faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're wanting to do all of this in TSQL?  Something like this would do it:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (tmpID INT IDENTITY, tblID INT)
DECLARE @RecordCount INT,
@LoopCount INT,
@ID INT

INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT id FROM MYTABLE
SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM @tmp
SET @LoopCount = 1

WHILE @LoopCount <= @RecordCount
  BEGIN

  SELECT @ID = tblID FROM @tmp WHERE tmpID = @LoopCount
  EXEC SELECT_DESCRIPTION @ID
  SELECT @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1

  END
```

The @tmp table has an identity column that insures whatever data you're running the loop on has consecutive row numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, etc).

Comment: That was a typo.  Should have been just @tmp.